# Idle animation defaults to one direction

Tags: godot, godot4

Simple problem, it's in the title. The problem is that every time I stop moving, it defaults to the SouthEast facing idle animation. This code comes from my previous post, with a few minor differences. Can someone fix this issue?

```
func updateAnimation():
    var direction_v := "Down"
    var direction_h := "Right"
    
    if input.x < 0.0:
        direction_h = "Left"
    elif input.x > 0.0:
        direction_h = "Right"

    if input.y < 0.0:
        direction_v = "Up"
    elif input.y > 0.0:
        direction_v = "Down"

    var direction := "_" + direction_v + direction_h
    
    if input == Vector2.ZERO:
        animation.play("walk" + direction + "Idle")
    else:
        animation.play("walk" + direction)
        
func _physics_process(delta):
    player_movement(delta)
    updateAnimation()
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time that the `updateAnimation` function runs, you are setting your `direction_h` and `direction_v` variables:

```
var direction_v := "Down"
var direction_h := "Right"
```

This is not desirable.

While these variable need some initial value, the code is indented to just keep the prior direction when the `input` is zero.

This why, in [the prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77209122/402022) I said to "declare, near the top of the script, two variables": they are indented to be script level variables (fields, if you will, or properties if you prefer), not local variables (which exist only while the method - `updateAnimation` - is running) that way they can keep their value.

The idea is more like this:

```
# extends blah blah blah

# OTHER DECLARATIONS

var direction_v := "Down"
var direction_h := "Right"

# PERHAPS MORE DECLARATION AND SOME OTHER CODE

func updateAnimation():   
    if input.x < 0.0:
        direction_h = "Left"
    elif input.x > 0.0:
        direction_h = "Right"

    if input.y < 0.0:
        direction_v = "Up"
    elif input.y > 0.0:
        direction_v = "Down"

    var direction := "_" + direction_v + direction_h
    
    if input == Vector2.ZERO:
        animation.play("walk" + direction + "Idle")
    else:
        animation.play("walk" + direction)

# EVEN MORE CODE
```

Now these would - while still having a default value - won't be reset every time `updateAnimation` run, instead they will retain their value from one call to the next.

Comment: Yep, now the animations 100% work! Thanks!